# How to create a Javascript Table Lens

Tags: javascript, d3.js, information-visualization

I'm needing to create a view for data in Table Lens format, my idea is to use the [d3js.org](http://d3js.org) library because I need it to be done in javascript. I wonder if someone has already developed something and can help.

This link shows a Table Lens example: http://complexdatavisualized.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/table-lens.gif (in this paper http://www.ramanarao.com/papers/tablelens-chi94.pdf)

Comment: Well, a quick search turns up [this](https://github.com/lvterry/learn-d3/blob/master/table_lens.html) and [this](https://github.com/carlmanaster/datastripes). In general, stackoverflow is more suited for specific questions rather than general queries. Most folks will expect you to post some actual code as part of your question, as they'd like to see that you've made some effort before resorting to others. Your question might get down voted for that reason (though not by me; I don't down vote.)

Comment: Thank @StephenThomas! as I not found sites with content about what I needed I decided to post code without it. Among the two references you said, the datastripes looks more like what I need, but I need that when clicked on the line, this is expanded. I'm working on a code to update my question....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RESOLVED:**

I'm solve the problem with this code:

```
var dadosRecursos = [
  {
       created_at: "2015-05-04T22:30:52.000Z", 
       curso_id: 13,
       fullname: "Vis. Curso 13",
       id: 149
  },
  { 
       created_at: "2015-05-04T22:30:52.000Z",
       curso_id: 13,
       fullname: "Recurso"id: 150,
  }];

var dadosTableLens = [
   {
       R149: 40,
       R150: 40,
       R151: 40,
       R152: 40,
       R153: 40,
       R154: 40,
       R155: 40,
       Ranalises: 140,
       aluno_id: 147
   },{
       R149: 30,
       R150: 20,
       R151: 40,
       R152: 70,
       R153: 40,
       R154: 80,
       R155: 40,
       Ranalises: 150,
       aluno_id: 144
   },
   {
       R149: 10,
       R150: 40,
       R151: 30,
       R152: 40,
       R153: 50,
       R154: 40,
       R155: 70,
       Ranalises: 100,
       aluno_id: 150
}];

var defHeight = 2;
var augHeight = 10;
var rRecs     = ["Ranalises"];

for (var i = 0; i <= dadosRecursos.length - 1; i++) {
    rRecs.push("R"+dadosRecursos[i].id);
};

d3.selectAll("thead td").data(rRecs).on("click", function(k) {
    d3.event.preventDefault();
    tr.sort(function(first, last) { 
        if (first[k] > last[k])
            return -1;
        else if (first[k] < last[k])
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    })
});

var tr = d3.select("tbody").selectAll("tr")
.data(dadosTableLens)
.enter()
  .append("tr")
  .attr("id", function(d){ return "A"+d.aluno_id; })

    .on("click", function(k, p) {
        d3.event.preventDefault();
        clicked(k, p);
    });

    tr.append("th")
        .html(function(d) { return "<span>"+d.aluno_id+"</span>" })
        .attr("class", "texto");

    tr.selectAll("td")
        .data(function(d) { return rRecs.map(function(k) { return d[k]; }); })
    .enter()
      .append("td")
        .append("svg")
                .attr("width", ($("._content-head").width()/(dadosRecursos.length+1.4)))
                .attr("height", defHeight)
            .append("rect")
                .attr("height", defHeight)
                .attr("width", function(d) { return d; });
}

var clicked = function(d, i){
var oldClick = d3.selectAll(".highlight");

  oldClick.classed("highlight", false);
oldClick
    .selectAll("rect")
    .attr("height", defHeight);

  oldClick          
    .selectAll("svg")
    .attr("height", defHeight)

nowClick = d3.select("tr#A"+d.aluno_id);

  nowClick.classed("highlight", true);
nowClick
    .selectAll("rect")
    .attr("height", augHeight);

  nowClick          
    .selectAll("svg")
    .attr("height", augHeight);
```

Thank's!